# how do I handle the links submitted, so that I can show those to everyone who visits foo.jsp?

Tags: java, servlets

I want the links that I submit from the control panel of my website to appear on a jsp page '*foo.jsp*' . Till know I was binding the links submitted ,as an attribute of the session object when I realized that session created by a servlet (that handled the links) was centric to that particular computer.

Is there any way I can achieve this besides using the database approach.

What I have been doing till know :

```
Post Request from the cpanel -----> Servlet handles the link and puts that link as a session attribute
                                              |
                                              |
                                             \ /
     foo.jsp tries to retrieve those links by calling session.getAttribute(....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in the application context (`getServletContext()`) instead of in session.

You may want to synchronize access to the app context list-of-links.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Did you try searching the web for "servlet application context"? It's one of the normal JEE scopes (application, session, request, page).

Comment: I understand application context.It is the scope/directory where all the application/project files,folders are present. Now do you want me to store all the links in a _xml_ file that should be placed inside the _application context_ ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta No, that's not the application context I'm talking about, I'm talking about application scope, one of the four scopes I listed in my comment. Would it be more clear if I said "servlet context" (which is what the code snippet says)? Nobody said anything about an XML file, I said a list of links.

Comment: @SuhailGupta ... http://suhail3.blogspot.com/2012/02/using-servletcontext.html Ironically on your own blog.

Comment: A web app is being visited after 10 years.Everything is the same as it was 10 years back.It has not been redeployed for 10 years. Now will it give me the same  value corresponding to _context.getAttribue("foo")_ ? I asked this because i was thinking if there is any time scope after which the data stored in the application context is deleted.

Comment: @grassPro No, as long as there's a reference to it, there shouldn't be a reason for a container to arbitrarily remove data from the application scope.

Comment: what do you mean by _reference to it_ ? what is the reference ?

Comment: @grassPro Java objects are eligible for garbage collection once nothing holds a reference to it (more or less). If the application context hold a reference to an object it shouldn't be arbitrarily cleared. There's no timeout for the application context--that's its point, to exist for the lifetime of the application, same as the other scopes.